# Is Python open(file,vr) supposed to update atime?

Tags: python, linux, file-io, filesystems

Whenever I `open()` a file with `Python`, the last access time is not updated, that's very odd :

If I open with `r/rb` nothing changes if I stat the file

If I open with `w/r+` or a the ctime and mtime update properly but not `atime`

It doesn't look like it is a filesystem problem (which is ext3 in this case) because if I touch or cat the file it does update properly.

I haven't been able to find a lot of information about it; is it supposed to behave this way or is there something wrong?

Comment: Maybe the filesystem is mounted with `notime`? Note that you'll need to actually read from the file to cause `atime` to be updated

Comment: Check the mounting options for `noatime`.

Comment: Nothing wrong in fstab, default mounting options and like I said, touch or cat will update the atime without any problem, I was just wondering if open() used a particular way to access the file which would not update the st_atime field

Comment: On modern Linux machines "relatime" is usually the default.

Comment: Even if relatime was in the defaults, if open() is supposed to update the atime it should update it

Comment: There is an option O_NOATIME to open(2), it might be worth using strace to find if python is using it (I would do it myself, but you don't say which python version and which OS).

Comment: I didn't think about that, I can't tell you right now because I don't have the VM at work, I'll check it out later, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try running `mount`, and see, if `noatime` flag is used on the mounted fs. Also, if your kernel is fresh enough, it's the "relatime" that is set by-default.

The "open()" code is pretty self-explanatory and does not mess with ATIME flags:

```
/* >> fileutils.c from Python 3.2.3 */

FILE*
_Py_fopen(PyObject *path, const char *mode)
{
#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
    wchar_t wmode[10];
    int usize;

    usize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, mode, -1, wmode, sizeof(wmode));
    if (usize == 0)
        return NULL;

    return _wfopen(PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(path), wmode);
#else
    FILE *f;
    PyObject *bytes = PyUnicode_EncodeFSDefault(path);
    if (bytes == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* >> Plain fopen(), nothing fancy here. */
    f = fopen(PyBytes_AS_STRING(bytes), mode);
    Py_DECREF(bytes);
    return f;
#endif
}
```

Comment: For future readers, relatime is defaultly hardcoded into the kernel since Linux kernel 2.6.30 with a default interval of 1 day, so unless the partition is mounted with strictatime (or noatime), it's active